# Elliptic curve ElGamal cryptosystems

Tags: elliptic-curves, elgamal-encryption

I have been working through a book on cryptography and have recently come across elliptic curves. This particular question has me stumped and the book isn't much help, unfortunately. I was wondering if someone was able to talk me through the process a little better. The question is:

Alice and bob use

- the prime p=83,
- an elliptic curve E: y^2 = x^3 + 5x + c (mod 83),
- and point P=(3,11) on E.

Alice chose k=2 but she needs help choosing her public key (p,P,Q,E)
where Q = kP (mod p). Find c so that the point P is on E, and find the point Q and the curve E. Also bob sends Alice the pair ((5, 48), (13, 10)). **What is the message?**

If there is a good resource for learning this style of the question then any suggestion is greatly appreciated! Thanks!